# Error on cURL request using php-cURL while sending SMS

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

> The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not
>   supported for this resource.\",\"ExceptionMessage\"unsure emoticon"No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'SmsQueue'
>   from content with media type
>   'multipart/form-data'.\",\"ExceptionType\"unsure
>   emoticon"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException\",\"StackTrace\"unsure
>   emoticon"   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable 1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\"}"

```
    // Prepare you post parameters
    $postArray = array(
        'APIKey' => AUTH_KEY,
        'number' => $mobile,
        'text' => $message,
        'senderid' => SENDER_ID,
        'channel' => $channel,
        'DCS' => $DCS,
        'flashsms' => $flashsms,
        'route' => $route
    );

    // Init the resource
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postArray
    ));

    // Ignore SSL certificate verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    // Get response
    $curlOutput = curl_exec($ch);

    // Print error if any
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Instead of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postArray` try `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postArray)`. I had a similar error posting to the Ecobee API and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks that works.

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postArray) not working

curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postRequest1));

Comment: Could you pls improve your answer by a) posting syntactically correct code, b) format your code using the markdown options of the editor, c) elaborate on the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set Content-Type in header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Use like this :

```
        $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://url.com",
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(['message' => test]),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ),
    ));
```