# PHP curl method API for sms is not working with POST Method

Tags: php, android, api, curl

[SEND SMS - API using curl method in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444262/send-sms-http-request-using-php-curl-getting-below-error)

Using the above link i am calling api, but it is not working giving the error as

> **error: malformed**
>   Here below my code,

```
//Prepare you post parameters
$postArray = array(
    'user' => 'myapi_username',
    'password' => 'myapi_password',
    'APIKey' => 'my_api_key******',
    'number' => 'mobile_number',
    'text' => 'sridhar testing',
    'senderid' => 'MEDLAB',
    'channel' => 'Trans',
    'DCS' => '0',
    'flashsms' => '0',
    'route' => '1'

);
```

// init the resource

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postArray)
        //,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
));


//Ignore SSL certificate verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);


//get response
$curlOutput = curl_exec($ch);

//Print error if any
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: change these line "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>http_build_query($postArray)" to "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$postArray" might be it will be work

Comment: replace the CURL with this ` $ch = curl_init();
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                            $data = curl_exec($ch);
                            curl_close($ch); 
                            print($data);  `

Comment: @DhavalBhavsar that is also not working ...

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz i forgot to give URL.. but now it's coming {"ErrorCode":"1","ErrorMessage":"login details cannot be blank","JobId":null,"MessageData":null}... How to reslove the issues?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
                    $username="*****"; //use your sms api username
                    $pass    =     "*******";  //enter your password
                    $dest_mobileno   = "******";//reciever 10 digit number (use comma (,) for multiple users. 
                    $senderid    =     "*****";//use your sms api sender id
                    $content = 'TEST%20SMS%20BOSS';     
                    $url2 = "http://login.blesssms.com/api/mt/SendSMS?user=".$username."&password=".$pass."&senderid=".$senderid."&channel=Trans&DCS=0&flashsms=0&number=".$dest_mobileno."&text=".$content."&route=1";
                    $url = rawurlencode($url);
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    $result=curl_exec($ch);
                    $curlerrno = curl_errno($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                    print $curlerrno;
```